# Call a regular view in Html.Partial?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

I have a regular view I'd like to use in another page, appearing magically in a jQuery-like accordion if the expand button is clicked.  If I call it using:

`Html.Partial(A_non_partial_view, new view_model_used_by_the_non_partial_view())`

...does that have a chance of working, or is MVC not plumbed that way?  (I'm using MVC 3 if that helps.)

Answer (score 0):

You can, but only if it is in the same controllers views folder or in the shared views folder.  otherwise you will have to specify that path fully which isn't practically really.

If you use Html.Action or Html.RenderAction, then that action will need to return a PartialView otherwise it will push out a full html page again with head tags etc etc